# How to group a list of dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts

```
[
  {"day":"10", "car":"bmw", "count":"3"},
  {"day":"10", "car":"audi", "count":"2"},
  {"day":"10", "car":"jeep", "count":"4"},
  {"day":"11", "car":"bmw", "count":"6"},
  {"day":"11", "car":"audi", "count":"7"},
  {"day":"11", "car":"jeep", "count":"8"},
]
```

I want to convert it to like this (desired output)

```
[
      {"day":"10", "bmw":"3","audi":"2","jeep":"4"},
      {"day":"11","bmw":"6","audi":"7","jeep":"8"},
]
```

this is what i did. is there any better and optimal way to achieve this.

```
def dl():
    list_of_dicts = [
            {"day":"10", "car":"bmw", "count":"3"},
            {"day":"10", "car":"audi", "count":"2"},
            {"day":"10", "car":"jeep", "count":"4"},
            {"day":"11", "car":"bmw", "count":"6"},
            {"day":"11", "car":"audi", "count":"7"},
            {"day":"11", "car":"jeep", "count":"8"},
            ]

    result = []
    data = {}

    for item in list_of_dicts:

        if not data.get(item["day"], False):    
            data[item["day"]] = []
            data[item["day"]].append({item["car"]:item["count"]})

        else:
            data[item["day"]].append({item["car"]:item["count"]})

    for key in data:
        new_dict = {}
        new_dict["day"] = key
        for item in data[key]:
            new_dict.update(item)
        result.append(new_dict)

    print result
    return result

dl()
```

If the question is not correct somebody please help me to

correct this question . i am a beginner

Comment: Provide a code example that you've at least attempted and we'll help you. Otherwise you're essentially asking us to do your homework.

Comment: Whenever I try to summarise something (in JavaScript and/or Python), I always try to look at the reduce function. (learn map, reduce, and filter functions - they all come handy for array / list manipulation) Take a look a this: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Comment: You really do need to read the [MCVE documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
But to answer, use reduce with a partial function.
`from functools import partial, reduce;
def f(day, x, y): x.update({y['car']: y['count']}) if y['day'] == day else x; return x;
days = {dict_['day'] for dict_ in dict_list};
output = [reduce(partial(f, day), dict_list, {'day': day}) for day in days]`

Comment: you all mean its not the platform for a beginner to ask the questions. its only for experts. @martineau,

Comment: This most certainly is a platform for beginners to ask questions about code they have written. It is not a platform for anyone, beginners or not, to have other people do their work for them. This is all clearly explained in the tutorial that is shown when you signed up.

Comment: @martineau  extremely sorry to all . i admit my mistakes now i understood the way i asked the question is not good. i will try my best not happen this on next time. i updated the question , i added what i tried to do .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` to group based on the day, then create a new dict for each day:

```
list_of_dicts = [
  {"day":"10", "car":"bmw", "count":"3"},
  {"day":"10", "car":"audi", "count":"2"},
  {"day":"10", "car":"jeep", "count":"4"},
  {"day":"11", "car":"bmw", "count":"6"},
  {"day":"11", "car":"audi", "count":"7"},
  {"day":"11", "car":"jeep", "count":"8"},
]

# to use groupby the list must be sorted
list_of_dicts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter("day"))

result_list = []
for day, dicts_for_that_day in itertools.groupby(list_of_dicts, key=operator.itemgetter("day")):
    day_dict = {'day': day}
    day_dict.update({d['car']: d['count'] for d in dicts_for_that_day})
    result_list.append(day_dict)

print(result_list)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to sort the list here

Comment: @Manjunath the example list is already sorted, but you do need them sorted otherwise the code won't be able to group all days together.

Comment: @nosklo thanks a loooooooooooooooooot.............. i dont know about itertools and operator before now .thanks a lot . can i use this way for 75 objects in a list . will it be effecient

Comment: you are really awesome